# Posting a form data using POST with PHP

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I have been looking into this for hours and still at a loss.

I have a PHP page (PAGE1.PHP) with a link and when the link is clicked by the user the PHP page would need to read some data from a database and post this data using POST to a third-party site.

I managed to do this with CURL however the problem is that although the data is posted and the third-party page does load correctly, the URL (in the browser) is still show as PAGE1.PHP as opposed to the third-party URL I posted to.

Is there a way how I can do this?

I have the option of creating a form on PAGE1.PHP with the data I read from the database set as hidden and the link as a submit.  I didn't try it yet but should work however this means that the data I am reading from the db can be read by the user by just viewing source.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: Looking for hours? You should be completely blind. There are thousands of similar questions already.

Comment: Yes I did look for hours .. and I didn't find anything - particularly due to my requirement "the URL (in the browser) is still show as PAGE1.PHP as opposed to the third-party URL I posted to.".  I tried CURL, I tried PHP Redirect, tried PEAR (but godaddy doesn't allow it) and more ... and im not even a developer!::)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use CURL to post it's your **web server** that's posting, not the user's browser.  So if any sessions or cookies are being used they won't carry over.

I'd do what you mentioned, creating a hidden form and posting the data that way.  You could be clever about it though and do a document.ready in jQuery and as soon as the hidden form is loaded you could post it for the user.  While there is still a small window of opportunity for them to view source it'd be a little more stream-lined.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hiddenForm').submit();
});
</script>
```

**Edit** Full example:

```
<?

  $urlToPostTo = 'http://www.thirdPartyDomain.com/login';
  $varsToPost['user'] = 'username';
  $varsToPost['pass'] = 'password';

  ?>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#hiddenForm').submit();
    });
  </script>
  <?

  echo '<form id="hiddenForm" action="'.$urlToPostTo.'" method="post">';

  /* create a hidden input for each var in 'varsToPost' */
  foreach($varsToPost as $varName=>$varValue) {
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.$varName.'" value="'.$varValue.'">';
  }

  echo '</form>';

?>
```

Just add / remove variables in the `$varsToPost` array and they'll automatically be plugged in.  I guess if you were passing a password / sensitive data you could always encrypt it in php and decrypt it in js right before the form submit.  This would still leave you open as anyone would have access to your decrypting function but it'd mask your data at a glance.

Even so, this form submit happens very quickly, it's hard to tell that it's being sneaky.

Comment: Ouch .. I don't know a lot of javascript although I can learn very fast.  Could you just at least let me know what I need to do in pseudo? I don't want to waste too much of your time.

Comment: Hey thanks ... will look into it.  You have been very helpful Chad :)

Comment: Worked out great - Thanks again Chad.  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

The URL in the browser correctly shows your original URL, because that's what the browser requested, and that's what served the request; your PHP page made a POST request behind the scenes to get the data, but it then served it back to your browser.

To get the result I think you want, you need to redirect the browser to make the post.  You're correct to be concerned with the issues of hidden data; sounds like you might need to do a bit of architecture work to resolve that problem.

Comment: Hmm .. any ideas on what sort of architecture work I need to do? Always keeping in mind that I can't modify the third party site.  The third-party site changes depending on the data I post.

Comment: @DavidV: tough to determine if you don't have any control over the third-party site; if you can do some means of doing a post from your PHP with the hidden data, and then providing the user's browser with a "non-sensitive" link to a page determined by that post, that might work.  It's really all determined by how the third-party site you're dealing with handles this sort of thing, and whether or not they require users to have that sensitive data you're handling or if there's some way to get around that requirement.

Comment: Will be using hidden form - not the best in security but for what I'm using its good enough .. security through obscurity is ok for this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [header function from PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) in order to make a real redirect with POST data.

Follow some sources for your reference.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

http://shiflett.org/articles/form-spoofing

Comment: Umm .. are you sure you could do that? from what I have been reading you the header functions don't support POST - as they are sent to the browser.

Comment: After some googling on this, yeah, it is not directly possible with PHP, unfortunately. But if javascript is not a problem, you can make an "autosubmit" form. Check it out: http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/59493-php-redirect-with-post-headers.html

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel At least I've tried contributing, instead of just making bad comments

Comment: Sure. That's what this lame site for: contributing. Education, thinking, common sense and experience are things nobody cares of. Go on, you gonna get shitload of rep here.

Comment: Education? Sorry but I really think you aren't in the position to talk about that. You made a non-constructive comment upon a serious answer which I was clearly following up. Stopping here, will not feed trolls nor start a pointless flaming.

Comment: Thanks Dave.  Seems to me similar to Chads way.

Comment: Yeap @David V, I was writing this answer when he posted, but in the bottomline, the solutions are identical.